# Glassfish Hot Deploy with File Synchronization

Tags: eclipse, maven, glassfish, glassfish-3

I was looking for someway to perform hot deployment on glassfish. I was find this guide:

http://entjavastuff.blogspot.se/2010/11/hot-deploying-from-eclipse.html

which is exactly what I am looking for. Unfortunately, this is for JBoss. I do not know how to handle it for Glassfish.

Can you please help me transform the part "Configure destinations" to Glassfish directories instead?

Best regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492643/how-can-i-hot-deploy-using-the-glassfish-adapter-in-eclipse

Comment: Hi, my project is a maven multi module project. I have been used that adapter in Eclipse with a simple web project, but I think that the adapter dont manage to work with a multi module proejct?

Answer (score 1):

It would be exactly the same, except, rather than pointing the synchronization of files to the  JBoss deploy directory, you would point them to the glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy directory.

Answer (score -1):

Forget that.

["File open failure" compiling java class to glassfish autodeploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317550/file-open-failure-compiling-java-class-to-glassfish-autodeploy)

If somebody find a Java EE 6 container you can do autodeploy, please share it. I have pass the last month trying do do an autodeploy on JBoss, WebLogic and Glassfish. It never worked.

Lesson learned: Do not use Java EE. Use Spring on a simple tomcat.

Comment: http://www.z2-environment.eu/home allows autodeploy (actually synchronization) and provides Spring support